Join and OrderBy statement very slow, 77 seconds, despite indexes
I'm having performance issues with MySQL, despite having indexes when using both join and order by . The query is currently taking 77 seconds to complete.
The purpose of the query is to order the table alphabetically.
Background
I have a MySQL database that contains two InnoDB tables.

report_urls; and
urls

Each table contains 500,000 records. There is a one-to-one relationship between report_urls and url. Whereas there is a one-to-many relationship between url and report_urls.
The tables have the following structure:

report_urls

id (Primary Key, char36, UUID, indexed)

url_id (char36, UUID, indexed)



urls

id (Primary Key, char36, UUID, indexed)

title (varchar 255, indexed)




I need to join these tables and order the joined results by alphabetically by the title column.
The query
I am using Laravel and the Eloquent ORM, but the SQL statement that is generated is:
select
  *
from
  `report_urls`
  inner join `urls` as `urls_title_sort` on `report_urls`.`url_id` = `urls_title_sort`.`id`
where
  `report_id` = '8f6598f0-34d0-48b0-be8b-41c1b8f61ffd'
order by
  `urls_title_sort`.`title` asc
limit
  11 offset 0

MySQL Explain
Running the above query with the EXPLAIN command outputs the following:



id
select_type
table
partitions
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
filtered
Extra




1
SIMPLE
report_urls
NULL
ref
report_urls_url_id_foreign,report_urls_report_id_created_at_index
report_urls_report_id_created_at_index
144
const
235931
100.00
Using temporary; Using filesort


1
SIMPLE
urls_title_sort
NULL
eq_ref
PRIMARY
PRIMARY
144
database.report_urls.url_id
1
100.00
NULL



Show CREATE
The output of SHOW CREATE TABLE report_urls; is as follows:
CREATE TABLE `report_urls` (
  `id` char(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `report_id` char(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `url_id` char(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `violation_count` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `resolved_violation_count` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `violation_minor` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `violation_moderate` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `violation_serious` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `violation_critical` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `report_urls_url_id_foreign` (`url_id`),
  KEY `report_urls_report_id_created_at_index` (`report_id`,`created_at`),
  KEY `report_urls_report_id_index` (`report_id`),
  KEY `report_urls_violation_count_index` (`violation_count`),
  KEY `report_urls_resolved_violation_count_index` (`resolved_violation_count`),
  KEY `report_urls_violation_minor_index` (`violation_minor`),
  KEY `report_urls_violation_moderate_index` (`violation_moderate`),
  KEY `report_urls_violation_serious_index` (`violation_serious`),
  KEY `report_urls_violation_critical_index` (`violation_critical`),
  KEY `report_urls_created_at_index` (`created_at`),
  CONSTRAINT `report_urls_report_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`report_id`) REFERENCES `reports` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `report_urls_url_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`url_id`) REFERENCES `urls` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Question
I need to join these tables together and sort them alphabetically by title.
The query currently takes 77 seconds to execute. I was hoping that MySQL could use the title index, but it doesn't seem to use the index.
Can anyone suggest any performance improvements?

Can you output the result from the query SHOW CREATE TABLE report_urls (or whichever table has the report_id column). I suspect adding an index on report_id would solve your problem.

Thanks, @IGP; I've updated the question above to show the about, as the comment did not allow enough characters. Thank you!

A many-to-many relationship rarely needs an id, get rid of it.  Then have these two indexes on report_urls:
INDEX(report_id, url_id)
INDEX(url_id, report_id)

These changes will speed up most queries using that table.  See also: Many-to-many
(The other columns and indexes can stay the same).
The use of UUIDs (GUIDs) for indexes are generally inefficient for large tables.  See also: UUIDs

you should not use order by urls_title_sort.title asc，because this will lead to use temporary table and scan all the rows.
